# Join extension function for Iterables (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

In Scala I have defined an extension function, so that I can join two Sequences, similiar like in SQL

```
implicit def SeqExtensions[X](first: Seq[X]) = new {
 def join[Y](second: Y) = new {
   def on(predicate: (X, Y) => Boolean) = {
     for (ff <- first; if predicate(ff, second)) yield (ff, second)
   }
 }
}
```

Example usage:

```
val joinSeq = unitComponents.flatMap(w => myOtherUnitComponents join w on { (u, w) =>
  w.cell equals u.cell
})
```

=> result type is Seq[(UnitComponent, UnitComponent)]

I now wanna do write the same extension in Kotlin (sequence type is not important, List/Collection is fine) but I am not profound enough yet to do this. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: In kotlin you can achieve this with the [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the same as the Scala code:

```
class IterableJoin<X, Y>(val first: Iterable<X>, val second: Y) {
    infix fun on(predicate: (X, Y) -> Boolean) =
        first.filter { predicate(it, second) }.map { it to second }
}

infix fun <X, Y> Iterable<X>.join(second: Y) = IterableJoin(this, second)
```

The invocation will be like this:

```
val joinSeq = unitComponents.flatMap { w ->
    myOtherUnitComponents join w on { u, w ->
        w.cell == u.cell
    }
}
```